# Charge density in thermionic emission

Tags: electric-current, charge

How can I calculate the charge density that is emitted by a hot filament by Thermionic emission?
[image]

I was thinking of using this equation since I know the current density and the velocity of the emitted electrons, am I correct?
[image]

Comment: Is $J$ the emission current density, or the current density in the wire?

Comment: emission current density